# Oracle Invalid Identifier Error: ORA-00904 In inserting subquery

Tags: oracle

I can't figure out what is the problem that is causing it. I have tried renaming "amount" I have tried changing what data type is transferred through, I tried just removing it, but then it says that End_Date is invalid once I do that. Here is the code.

```
INSERT INTO price
( price_id
, item_id
, price_type
, active_flag
, start_date
, end_date
, amount
, created_by
, creation_date
, last_updated_by
, last_updated)

(SELECT price_s1.nextval
,      il.Item_ID
,      il.Price_Type
,      il.Active_Flag
,      il.Start_Date
,      il.End_Date
,      il.amount
,      1
,      SYSDATE
,      1
,      SYSDATE 
FROM    (SELECT i.item_id AS "Item_ID"
        , af.active_flag AS "Active_Flag"
        , cl.common_lookup_id AS "Price_Type"
        , cl.common_lookup_type AS "Price_Desc"
        ,    CASE    
             WHEN (TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 30) > TRUNC(i.release_date) THEN TRUNC(i.release_date) + 31
             ELSE TRUNC(i.release_date)
             END AS "Start_Date"
        ,    CASE
             WHEN (TRUNC(SYSDATE)-30) > TRUNC(i.release_date) AND active_flag = 'N' THEN
             TRUNC(i.release_date) + 30
             ELSE   
                null
             END AS "End_Date"
        ,    CASE
                 WHEN active_flag = 'N' AND cl.common_lookup_type = '1-DAY RENTAL' THEN 3
                 WHEN active_flag = 'N' AND cl.common_lookup_type = '3-DAY RENTAL' THEN 10
                 WHEN active_flag = 'N' AND cl.common_lookup_type = '5-DAY RENTAL' THEN 15
                 WHEN i.release_date+1 > (SYSDATE-1) AND cl.common_lookup_type = '1-DAY RENTAL' THEN 3
                 WHEN i.release_date+1 > (SYSDATE-1) AND cl.common_lookup_type = '3-DAY RENTAL' THEN 10
                 WHEN i.release_date+1 > (SYSDATE-1) AND cl.common_lookup_type = '5-DAY RENTAL' THEN 15
                 WHEN active_flag = 'Y' AND i.release_date +1 < (SYSDATE-1) THEN cl.common_lookup_code
             END AS "amount"

             FROM     item i CROSS JOIN
                (SELECT 'Y' AS active_flag FROM dual
                 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 'N' AS active_flag FROM dual) af CROSS JOIN
                (SELECT '1' AS rental_days FROM dual
                 UNION ALL
                 SELECT '3' AS rental_days FROM dual
                 UNION ALL
                 SELECT '5' AS rental_days FROM dual) dr INNER JOIN
                 common_lookup cl ON dr.rental_days = SUBSTR(cl.common_lookup_type,1,1)
        WHERE    cl.common_lookup_table = 'PRICE'
        AND      cl.common_lookup_column = 'PRICE_TYPE'
        AND NOT (active_flag ='N' AND (TRUNC(SYSDATE)-30) < TRUNC(i.release_date))
        ORDER BY 1, 2, 3) il);
```

I get the error at

```
,      il.amount
```

and this is what it says

```
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "IL"."AMOUNT": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Any help would be appreciated, if you need more info, just ask. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using quotes for alias names you specify a particalur case sensitive name.

```
CASE ... END AS "amount"
```

specifies the alias name to be `"amount"` in lowercase. If you want to access it, use excatly the same spelling. E.g. `"Amount"` would be invalid.

You are trying to access

```
il.amount
```

and as there are no quotes, you say: "I don't care about upper/lower case". That works when accessing table and column names directly or when using an alias name without quotes. But as you used `"amount"` before, `amount` cannot be found (you were lucky if it would; I guess it *could*  happen with an alias name with all upper chars, as Oracle uses upper chars for its names internally, but you wouldn't want to rely on this).

I suggest you just remove the quotes. Try to avoid them whenever possible. Use names that work without quotes (which you are actually already doing; none of your alias names contains any blank, leading digit or whatever).

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. So I changed it to END AS amount and it worked.